# Scope error in constructor (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, referenceerror

I've encountered a strange error
while I was working with the new version of ES6. When I run this piece of code I'm getting `ReferenceError: alertBox is not defined`. Is there any way to call alertBox inside this function? Thanks in advance :)

Here's the code

```
class main {
    constructor(data){
    this.data=data;

    // this one works
    this.alertBox(this.data);

    this.watchFile(function(){
      // this one throws error
      this.alertBox(this.data);
    });
    }

  alertBox(data){
    alert(data);
  }

  watchFile(cb){
    cb("changed");
  }
}

// app.js
new main("hello");
```

Here you can find the snippet: https://repl.it/FJUo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing a normal function into `watchFile` you're losing the context of `this`. In ES6 you can use "arrow function" syntax to create a function which keeps the correct context.

```
this.watchFile(() => {
    this.alertBox(this.data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, I didn't know that I have to use arrow functions for that particular reason. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yep, before ES6 you had to manually bind `this` to a normal function, but with arrow functions you get this behaviour for free.